# ServiceStack Admin UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I'm trying to integrate the `/admin-ui` functionality in my application, that uses the ServiceStack's built-in ApiKeyAuthProvider, for give the user the possibility to register other users. 
In the login page that this functionality renders, when I write my apikey and press the sign in button, through the developer tool console, I see the error "!AuthProvider", that sounds like that the app cannot recoignize the ApiKeyAuthProvider. 
This is my AppHost Configure method:

```
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        //Create and register an OrmLite DB Factory configured to use Live DB by default 
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
            AppSettings.Get<string>("connString"), SqlServerDialect.Provider);

        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);

        //Tell ServiceStack you want to persist User Auth Info in SQL Server
        container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
        container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();

        //Register the AuthFeature with the API Key Auth Provider 
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
            new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings)
        }));

        Plugins.Add(new AdminUsersFeature());
    }
```

Could someone help me please? (ServiceStack v.6.0.2) 
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please update your question to include the full StackTrace, please always do this for Exceptions.

Comment: done, sorry @mythz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should be resolved from the latest v6.0.3 pre-release that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

If you have an existing ServiceStack v6.0.3 installed you'll need to [clear your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#adding-myget-feed-without-vs-net) to update to the latest version, e.g:

```sh
$ nuget locals all -clear
```